# How to validate confirm password field at 4th character in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
    password: {
      required: required,
      minLength: minLength(8),
    },
```

```html
    <!-- Password -->
    <label class="form__group is-required">
      <span class="form__label">Password</span>
      <input
        class="form__input"
        type="password"
        name="form-password"
        v-model="password"
        @input="$v.password.$touch"
      />
      <p v-if="$v.password.$dirty">
        <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.password.required">Required.</span>
        <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.password.minLength">
          {{ $v.password.$params.minLength.min }} letters at least.
        </span>
      </p>
    </label>
    <!-- Repeat Password -->
    <label class="form__group is-required">
      <span class="form__label">Repeat<br />password </span>
      <input
        class="form__input"
        type="password"
        name="form-repeat-password"
        v-model="repeatPassword"
        @input="$v.repeatPassword.$touch"
      />
      <p v-if="$v.repeatPassword.$dirty">
        <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.repeatPassword.required"
          >Required.</span
        >
        <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.repeatPassword.sameAsPassword">
          Must be identical.
        </span>
      </p>
    </label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

```html
repeatPassword: {
  required: required,
  sameAsPassword: (value, vm) =>
    value === vm.password.substring(0, value.length),
},
```

I want to validate confirm password field at 4th character in Vuejs?  At present it is checking from the first character, tried using value.length < 5 but it doesn't work.

I have updated my input fields with vuelidate code

[image]

Comment: Why do you want `.substring(0, value.length)`? If the password is `12345678` and repeat password is `123` then your code will pass the case.

Comment: I think [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67111603-v9nfc?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) is the UX that you want, mate

Comment: Changed from validation **on input** to **on blur** (`v-model="password" @input="$v.password.$touch"` to `v-model.lazy="password" @blur="$v.password.$touch"`). And remove `.substring(0, value.length)` because it doesn't make sense. Now `sameAsPassword: (value, vm) => value === vm.password`. For better UX change from `:disabled="!agreement || $v.$invalid"` to `:disabled="!agreement"` on submit button as well.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh Thanks for the answer, Replaced the above given code. But still it is Checking from the 1st character in confirmpassword field.

But need to check like, If the password is 12345678 and repeat password is 123. From the 4th character i need to validate. if 1,2,3 characters not same it should not display any validation.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh  These is the code  after changes https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67111603-forked-sj1gu?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to display the validation when `repeatPassword` contains less than 4 characters (it's weird why you need that btw), then just add it `&& repeatPassword.length >= 4` on the code like so.

```
<p v-if="$v.repeatPassword.$dirty && repeatPassword.length >= 4"> 
<!-- only display the validation when length >= 4 -->
  <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.repeatPassword.required"
    >Required.</span
  >
  <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.repeatPassword.sameAsPassword">
    Must be identical.
  </span>
</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple **If()else{}** way

```
      watch: {
        repeatPassword(v) {
//checking repeat password length is 4 or greater then 4
          if(v.length >= 4){
//then checking if repeat password is same as password
            if(v === this.password){
              console.log('Passwords are same')
            }else{
              console.log('No a same password')
            }
          }else{
            console.log('validate start after Repeat password length 4')
          }
        },
      },
```

working example: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67111603-v9nfc?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Tried the above in the watch, But it is validating from the 1st character

Comment: You mean all validation like required and other thing from 4th character?

Comment: I mean, If the password is 12345678 and repeat password is abc. From the 4th character i need to validate.Although in confirm password field starting  if  i give a,b,c characters not same it should not display any validation.

Comment: Add my code into yours , my code works perfectly like your said condition

Comment: Tried add above code, But still same . Correct me if i am wrong

If possible can u please correct in sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67111603-forked-6evnl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue